# Getting undefined error notice in console even though I'm checking for undefined

Tags: javascript

This code:

```
if(typeof(Listings.page_num) != 'undefined') {
   // something
}
```

Triggers this notice in firebug console:

```
Listings is not defined http://mysite.com/js/content_ads.js Line 13
```

Well duh, that's why I checked! Is there any way to get rid of this notice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this.

```
var Listings = Listings || {};
if (typeof Listings.page_num !== "undefined") // page_num isset
```